# Python Beautifulsoup finding correct tag

Tags: python

I'm having a problem trying to figure out how to grab the specific tag I need.

```
<div class="meaning"><span class="hinshi">［名］</span><span class="hinshi">(スル)</span></div>, <div class="meaning"><b>１</b> 今まで経験してきた仕事・身分・地位・学業などの事柄。履歴。「―を偽る」</div>,
```

Right now I have it so it finds all the meaning classes, but I need to narrow it down even further from this to get what I want. Above is an example. I need to grab just the

```
"<div class="meaning"><b>".
```

and ignore all the "hinshi" classes.

edit: It seems to be showing the number, which I guess is what  is, but I need the text next to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a specific attribute by using keyword arguments to the `find` method. In your case, you'll want to match on the `class_` keyword. See the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) regarding the `class_` keyword.

Assuming that you want to filter the elements that don't contain any children with the "hinshi" class, you could try something like this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
potential_matches = soup.find_all(class_="meaning")

matches = []
for match in potential_matches:
  bad_children = match.find_all(class_="hinshi")
  if not bad_children:
    matches.append(match)

return matches
```

If you'd like, you could make it a little shorter, for example:

```py
matches = soup.find_all(class_="meaning")
return [x for x in matches if not x.find_all(class_="hinshi")]
```

Or, depending on your Python version, i.e. 2.x:

```py
matches = soup.find_all(class_="meaning")
return filter(matches, lambda x: not x.find_all(class_="hinshi"))
```

**EDIT:** If you want to find the foreign characters next to the number in your example, you should first remove the `b` element, then use the `get_text` method. For example

```py
# Assuming `element` is one of the matches from above
element.find('b').extract()
print(element.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `.select` function, which takes a CSS selector:

```
soup.select('.meaning b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you can do it like this,

```
for s in soup.findAll("div {class:meaning}"):
    for b in s.findAll("b"):
     #   b.getText("<b>")
```

And in '#' line, you should accord the result to fix it.